# grep between two files

Tags: linux, grep

I want to find matching lines from file 2 when compared to file 1.

file2 contains multiple columns and column one contains information that could match file1.

I tried below commands and they didn't give any matching results (contents in file1 are definitely in file2)  . I have used these commands previously to compare between different files and they worked.

```
grep -f file1 file2
grep -Fwf file1 file2
```

When i tried to grep whatever that's not matching, i get results

```
grep -vf file1 file2
```

file1 contains list of genes (754 genes) , one line each

```
ATM
ATP5B
ATR
ATRIP
ATRX
```

I have a feeling the problem is with my file1. When I tried to type several items manually in my file1 just to test, and do grep with file2, I get the matching lines from file2.

When I copied the contents of file1 (originally in excel) into notepad making a .txt file, I didn't get any matching results.

I can't see any problem with my file1. Any suggestion?

Comment: Using **diff** might be better.

Comment: I would have thought that `grep -wf file1 file2` would have worked.  If it didn't, there may be something wrong with your input files.  (Like, maybe, you've got a new `file1` that's a Windows file and there's an extra `^M` on every line.)

Comment: Shot in the dark: try saying `tr -d '\015' < file1 > file1a` and then `grep -Fwf file1a file2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said,

> I copied the contents of file1 (originally in excel) into notepad making a .txt file

It's likely that the txt file contains carriage-return/linefeed pairs which are screwing up the grep.  As I suggested in a comment, try this:

```
tr -d '\015' < file1 > file1a
grep -Fwf file1a file2
```

The `tr` invocation deletes all the carriage returns, giving you a proper Unix/Linux text file with only newlines (`\n`) as line terminators.

---

You said:

> I can't see any problem with my file1.

Here's how to see the extra-carriage-return problem:

```
cat -v test1
```

Those little `^M` markers at the end of each line are `cat -v`'s way of showing you the carriage return control codes.

---

Addendum:
Carriage Return (CR) is decimal 13, hex 0x0d, octal 015, `\r` in C.
Line Feed (LF) is decimal 10, hex 0x0a, octal 012, `\n` in C.
Because it's an old-school utility, `tr` accepts octal (base 8) notation for control characters.
(I think in some versions `tr -d '\r'` would work, but I'm not sure, and anyway I'm not sure what version you have.  `tr -d '\015'` should be universal.)

Comment: Yes.. I'd suspected there will be some weird characters in the file but not too sure how to 'see' them and remov them. Your suggestion works perfectly. Thank you. Do you mind explaining what the '\015' supposed to mean?

Comment: @JanShamsani See addendum in answer.

Answer (score 2):

Simple shell script that performs grep for every input in file1.txt

```
#!/bin/bash
while read content; do
    grep -q "$content" file2.txt
    if [ $? -eq "0" ]; then
        echo "$content" was found in file2 >> results.txt
    fi
done < file1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose this is file2:

```
$ cat file2
a b ATM
c d e
f ATR g
```

#### Using grep and process substitution

We can get lines from file1 that match any of the columns in file2 via:

```
$ grep -wFf <(sed 's/[[:space:]]/\n/g' file2) file1
ATM
ATR
```

This works because it converts file2 to a form that `grep` understands:

```
$ sed 's/[[:space:]]/\n/g' file2
a
b
ATM
c
d
e
f
ATR
g
```

#### Using awk

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) seen[$i]; next} $0 in seen' file2 file1
ATM
ATR
```

Here, awk keeps track of every column that it sees in file2 and then print only those lines in file1 that match one of those columns

Comment: hi, i tried the grep and sed command but I'm getting things that don't match also. the awk command didn't work.

Comment: I'll be happy to look at that.  Please add to the end of your question (a) a short sample of your file2 and (b) the output that you would like from that file2 and the file1 in the question.  That will allow me to tell why it isn't working for you.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use command

```
comm
```

it is a reversed version  of diff

Comment: tried that before when I was looking for solution here but it didn't work also